# How can I use a variable inside of the request body?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to use a variable (that I already defined in my scenario) inside of my JSON body request, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Is this not allowed? If not, is there a workaround? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**: This question was marked as a duplicate, and I've been reading the proposed solution for the other question ("Passing variables into Examples section [duplicate]"), but I'm not sure if it is the same case. I forgot to mention that in my example, the "parent" variable is dynamic (it is not a value that I can predict, sometimes it maybe '12' as the image suggests, but on another software version, it may be '50', so I cannot create a file like kittens.json with all the values beforehand). I only find out the value of this 'parent' variable when doing the GET request, and then I need this value for the PUT request (to use inside of the request body). I hope I made my question more clear - and thank you in advance for all the help provided!